# Heap corruption in std::string?

Tags: c++

My code fails with `Heap corruption in std::string?`

```
string unsigned_int_to_string(unsigned int in)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    using boost::spirit::karma::generate;

    char x[65];
    char *p = x;
    generate(p, uint_, in);
    *p = '\0';

    return string(x);
}
```

```
void add(string &s, unsigned int in)
{
    string d = unsigned_int_to_string(in);
    s += d+":";
}
```

If I run my program on a windows 7 PC it works OK but it crashes in random places on a windows 8.1 PC. Why heap corruption, I simply don't understand? Is there any chance my RAM is failing or any other programs cause issues?

**The corruption happens in at least 2 cases:**

a) `threadex.c` (code too long to post)
b) `free.c` called by `xstring` (code as shown above, too long to post more)

Comment: I very much doubt your RAM is failing.  Can you post some more code?

Comment: What is `d`? It just appears out of nowhere in your code... It would be a good idea to "finish the example" - the minimum number of lines we can post into a compiler to reproduce your problem.

Comment: When you set `*p = '\0';` you are truncating that (C) string to length 0...

Comment: Yes but I don't care about p as I use x as return

Comment: Typically, if you want a `std::string` from `generate`, you would pass it a `std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>` as the first parameter instead of a pointer to a character buffer.  If I had to guess, I'd say your problem is that you are going beyond the buffer you have allocated.  If you switch to using the back_insert_iterator method, your problem will likely go away.

Comment: Still why does it crash on threadex.c? I mean my program worked fine and I just changed a few **unrelated** things and now it's broken...

Comment: @Luka If I'm correct and you are somehow going outside the bounds for your character buffer (`generate` shouldn't do it as your `unsigned int` should not require 65+ characters, but ...) the error could happen anywhere.  You would be trashing memory.

Comment: @Luka: Well `p` refers to `x`, so yes, you do care.  Your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, using `boost::spirit::karma::generate` to return a string does not require you to use a character buffer first:

```
std::string unsigned_int_to_string(unsigned int value)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    using boost::spirit::karma::generate;
    std::string str;
    generate(std::back_inserter(str), uint_, value);
    return str;
}
```

What is likely happening:  somewhere in your code, `x` (being an unintialized character array of a fixed size) is being accessed beyond its bounds.  This would result in you trashing memory and after that anything can happen.

If that is not occurring, you are likely trashing memory in some other location of your code which is resulting in undefined behavior.

The long and the short of it:  you are invoking undefined behavior *somewhere* in your code.

As an aside, if you are using a C++11-compliant compiler, [`std::to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is somewhere else, not inside this function.

Most likely `s` and/or `d` are corrupt. Without seeing more code it's impossible to know why. If I had to guess, I'd think their memory has already been freed (for instance, if they are part of a class object and that class object is already deleted). Or perhaps another section of code is doing something wrong and overwriting their memory.

Comment: @Luka Undefined behavior is, *undefined*.  It *might* work fine ... or it might order a pizza, or reformat your hard drive, or call all of your ex-girlfriends.  As it is undefined behavior, any of those options (and any other option) is equally valid.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I posted the 2 cases corruption happens.

Comment: @ZacHowland, if my code would order pizza as undefined behaviour, I'd be writing a lot shittier code.  I might get fired.. but.. pizza...

Comment: @Moo-Juice There is nothing in the standard that would prevent code that invokes UB from ordering you a pizza ;)